# fork without copying the entire memory

Tags: c++, fork

How can I mark data structures that wont be copied on fork?

I have a program that uses fork() and I cannot modify it.
The program loads a shared library that uses threads, and was written in C++.

Since threads are not duplicated on fork, I am afraid that I loose references to some objects that I allocated on of the threads.

How can I avoid that?
Is there an option to mark objects that wont be copied on fork()?

I am writing a library that I load with the application in order to override some of it's function and force it to communicate with a remote server.
The library creates a thread that runs in the background.
The program calls fork().
And I must use boost objects for all threads/shared memory.

Thanks.

Comment: Are these objects stored in *thread local storage* then?

Comment: Have you tested your hypothesis?

Comment: Why did you mention the library? If I understand correctly you are forking a threaded program and want to know which objects are "lost"

Comment: Also, are you planning to call `exec` after the fork? If you do, then it doesn't matter. If you don't, make sure you really need to fork().

Comment: Not in this universe. How do you imagine a `fork` that copies some data structures but not others?

Comment: I am writing a library that I load with the application in order to override some of its function and force it to communicate with a remote server. The library creates a thread. and the program calls fork().

Comment: You may want to use `pthread_atfork()` in order to track objects in different threads instead.